# Sorting two arraylists into a new sorted list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am working on a project so I've simplified my problem to this:

Given two arraylists that are sorted in decending order, I want to take each of their values and put them into a new arraylist.

The new arraylist has a size capacity of 5 maximum.

So this seems to be pretty easy maybe I am just having a brainfart but here is my code, I keep getting nullpointer exception and I have NO IDEA WHY

```
        int l1ptr = 0;
        int l2ptr = 0;
        while(searchList.size() < 5 || (listOne.get(l1ptr) == null && listTwo.get(l2ptr) == null)){
            if(listOne.get(l1ptr) == null){
                searchList.add(listTwo.get(l2ptr).document);
                l2ptr++;
            }else{
                if(listTwo.get(l2ptr) == null){
                    searchList.add(listOne.get(l1ptr).document);
                    l1ptr++;
                }else{
                    if(listOne.get(l1ptr).frequency < listTwo.get(l2ptr).frequency){
                        searchList.add(listTwo.get(l2ptr).document);
                        l2ptr++;
                    }else{
                        if(listTwo.get(l2ptr).frequency < listOne.get(l1ptr).frequency){
                            searchList.add(listOne.get(l1ptr).document);
                            l1ptr++;
                        }else{
                            searchList.add(listOne.get(l1ptr).document);
                            l1ptr++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

SearchList is the new arraylist I want to return.

The two lists given are lists of objects, which store both a string(document) and number(frequency).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you log the exception, it should tell you in what line is the problem. Why not provide that bit of information?
I see the last else block is identical to the "then" block above it. Copy paste error?

Comment: @hidralisk I was getting exception on my while statement condition, I think it was because I was trying to access an item from an array to check if it was null, but it threw the null pointer exception lol. I did not know that was how it worked because for example in linked lists, you can check if a value in the list is null, but apparently in arraylists you can't do that or I get exception so I used a different condition and it worked now

Comment: it is possible to check if the value in the array list is null, without exceptions. People do this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to merge two sorted lists,
up to maximum 5 elements.
Consider this generalized logic:

- Repeat while `searchList.size() < 5` *and* `l1ptr` is not at the end of the first list *and* `l2ptr` is not at the end of the second list

  - The loop will stop when either you have 5 elements, or reached the end of one of the lists
- Repeat while `searchList.size() < 5` *and* `l1ptr` is not at the end of the first list

  - The loop will stop when either you have 5 elements, or reached the end of the first list
  - Note that if you have already reached the end of the first list in the first loop, then this loop will simply do nothing
- Repeat while `searchList.size() < 5` *and* `l2ptr` is not at the end of the second list

  - The loop will stop when either you have 5 elements, or reached the end of the second list
  - Note that if you have already reached the end of the second list in the first loop, then this loop will simply do nothing
- At the end, you will have `searchList` with at most 5 elements, correctly ordered

Like this:

```
while (searchList.size() < 5 && l1ptr < listOne.size() && l2ptr < listTwo.size()) {
    if (listOne.get(l1ptr).frequency < listTwo.get(l2ptr).frequency) {
        searchList.add(listTwo.get(l2ptr).document);
        l2ptr++;
    } else {
        searchList.add(listOne.get(l1ptr).document);
        l1ptr++;
    }
}

while (searchList.size() < 5 && l1ptr < listOne.size()) {
    searchList.add(listOne.get(l1ptr).document);
    l1ptr++;
}

while (searchList.size() < 5 && l2ptr < listTwo.size()) {
    searchList.add(listTwo.get(l2ptr).document);
    l2ptr++;
}
```

Comment: This is for generic case. If your initial 2 lists are bigger than 5, then you only need the first loop.